# Lucene.net optimize unfinished loop

Tags: .net, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.net version 2.9.1, and facing the following problem when calling Optimize:
I've noticed that some calls to optimize can take hours, and when this take that long period, the process which indexing and optimizing isn't kill-able.
When I used the source code, I managed to track the problem: the call which is causing this behavior is `Optimize(int maxNumSegments, bool doWait)` - and within this method there're repetitive calls to `OptimizeMergesPending()` which always return true, and the loop keep working and call this method until this call will return otherwise, which can take ages.

This raise the following questions:
1. What can cause `OptimizeMergesPending()` keep return true?
2. What can cause the failure of killing the process that indexes and optimizing?
3. Do you know if newer versions of Lucene.net face the same behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [xmldocs for IndexWriter.OptimizeMergesPending](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net/blob/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g/src/core/Index/IndexWriter.cs#L3385) states that it will return true "if any merges in pendingMerges or runningMerges are optimization merges". The [inline documentation for IndexWriter.DoWait](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net/blob/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g/src/core/Index/IndexWriter.cs#L6404) states that it will only wait for one second to avoid issues where some notifications may not be triggered, it's up to the caller to reevaluate the waiting conditions. I've linked to the 2.9.4g source code, so newer versions also contains this behavior.

An unkillable process is an operating system issue, you should always be able to kill a process as long as it isn't blocked in a kernel/system call. We would need to see process dumps to debug those issues. (Or a better explanation on how you're trying to kill the process...)

Counter-questions;

1. Why are you calling `IndexWriter.Optimize`? Lucene can handle several segments, in fact, it's easier to reopen indexes when only a few segments have changed than to reopen a completely new segment containing the whole index. You could write your own `MergePolicy` if you have issues with the current handling of segments. [It has been deprecated as of 3.5](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#optimize%28%29), which Lucene.Net currently lags behind (it's up to 3.0.3 at the moment, and porting of 4.x is in progress).
2. Are you ever locking on your IndexWriter? The code I linked showed that the code did `lock (this) {...}` which is bad and may cause deadlock issues for you in case you lock on your writer too. This may appear as if your code hangs and any clean thread termination you may have built will not be triggered (since the thread just blocks).

### Update regarding a continuously changing index.

1. Never call `IndexWriter.Optimize()`, it will cause unnecessary cpu- and io load, both during the actual merge and when reopening your readers.
2. Reopen your reader and searcher on a separate thread, or when calling IndexWriter.Commit. Do not wait until a user needs to search to reopen it.
3. Call IndexReader.Reopen() instead of IndexReader.Open(). The first one will only load changed segments and reuse those already read and not changed. (And remember, deletions are just a separate bitmap, it will only re-read the bitmap and not the complete segment.)
4. Consider upgrading to Lucene.Net 3.0.3 and using the IndexWriter.IndexReaderWarmer to write custom warmup logic to ensure your segments are fully read into cache/memory before users are starting to use it.

Comment: Regarding your first answer: In what way "it's easier to reopen indexes when only a few segments have changed..." ?  regarding the second answer: I don't think I'm experiencing dead-lock, it's just repetitive "true" returns in  `OptimizeMergesPending() `.

Comment: Do you think it's worth just changing the overload of `Optimize` to `Optimize(false)` ?

Comment: Segments are readonly and will not change. That means that calling `IndexReader.Reopen` will only need to read those files that are new (often small files due to small normal merges). Calling `IndexWriter.Optimize` will basically generate a new copy of the index in the same folder, requiring a call to `IndexReader.Reopen` to read the largest possible amount of data. I would avoid calling `IndexWriter.Optimize` completely in a real-time search scenario, but I have no idea what you're doing, how much data you got or your normal usage patterns. Also, take a memory dump for the process hangs.

Comment: few comments: "..Are you ever locking on your IndexWriter?.." I'm using the official 2.9.1 release, I didn't code anything, so the deadlock you mentioned - is not something I control. What I mean is, the writer IS locking (as you can see in [Optimize(int maxNumSegments, bool doWait)](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net/blob/Lucene.Net_2_9_4g/src/core/Index/IndexWriter.cs#L3336).

Comment: what scenario, in your opinion, is a "must optimize" scenario, and what is a "must not optimize"?? my index is written constantly. If I choose not to optimize, theoretically it'll cause some searching-time increase, right?

Comment: Updated the answer with some points regarding your constantly changing index. I have never seen any issues with never calling Optimize(). A theory would be that reopening your index would take longer time since there are more files involved, but seriously, how many files do your index actually consist of? Start worrying when this actually becomes a problem, and then consider other merging policies to trim down the number of segments instead of calling Optimize.

Comment: My concern is if I won't call Optimize, it'll increase the amount of files, which will in increase opening time... and this is because our site constructs IndexSearcher each search (I guess this is very bad...). My question is: assuming I stick with the per-call-IndexSearcher, will not calling Optimize is still relevant?

Comment: Stop worrying and try it out. Reuse your IndexSearcher, it's thread-safe. Stop calling Optimize.

Comment: I accepted @simon svensson's answer, even though it's not a solution for the resource problem and the unexplained infinite loop - those won't occur if OPTIMIZE won't be called.